# What is the rule for something divided by itself equaling 1?

Tags: axioms

Is there a name for the mathematical rule/axiom/property $x/x = 1?$

What are the conditions for it to apply?

For instance, the rule does not apply where $x = 0$ or $x = \inf$. I saw one site that claimed it only applied to real numbers, but it *does* apply to imaginary ones too, so that rule is not complete.

What is the complete rule and what is its name?

Comment: I figure it's pretty obvious for natural numbers, then extrapolated up from there to other types of numbers.

Comment: I would say it's "existence of inverse"; if you have a group $(G,\bullet,e)$, then for every $g\in G$ there exists an $h$ such that $g\bullet h=1$, and we write $h=g^{-1}$, to accommodate the familiar notation of $g\bullet g^{-1}=e$. Inverses are defined with respect to some binary notation; in a ring there exists for every element an additive inverse, but not necessarily a multiplicative inverse; in a field (such as the reals) it applies to every non-zero number (Note for you inf, which I take means $\infty$, is NOT a real number, so don't treat it as one).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Rather than viewing division as an operation in its own right (that would take a dividend and a divisor to a quotient), mathematicians think about *inverses* of multiplication. So one thinks of $\frac x y$ as $x · y^{-1}$ where $y^{-1}$ is, *by definition*, a number *inverse* to $y$, i.e. fulfilling $y·y^{-1} = 1 = y^{-1}·y$.

For example $\frac 3 2$ is rather thought of as “three halfs” (where a half is the inverse of two) than “three divided by two”. (Well, but one still uses the latter parlance, in fact.)

Therefore, I don’t think there is a name for this arithmetic law itself, at least I don’t know of one. But there’s of course one for the concept of [inverse elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_element). A more fundamental concept is that of [neutral elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutral_element), on which the concept of inverses depend.

And by the way: Division isn’t viewed as an operation by itself because it behaves badly: It is not totally defined as a map, say $ℚ × ℚ → ℚ$ (you can’t divide by zero), it fails to be associative, let alone commutative, and it doesn’t have a neutral element.

Comment: That's a well formulated answer.

Comment: so what is $y^{-1}$, for example $0^{-1}$ or $\infty^{-1}$. Isn't it true that $0^{-1}=\infty$ and $\infty^{-1}=0$, and is it true that $0\cdot\infty=1$?

Comment: @Mirko: no, many times no. $\infty$ is not a number! Mathematicians use $\infty$ as a shorthand for various phenomena, and sometimes use "equations" involving $\infty$ to refer to related phenomena; but these are not actual equations of numbers, because $\infty$ is not a number. $0^{-1}$ doesn't exist.

Comment: @GregMartin But if $0^{-1}$ doesn't exist, then inverses "behave badly" and I do not follow the point in the above answer to replace division with inverses, how does that really help answer the original question?

Comment: @Mirko: The inverse $x^{-1}$ exists for any $x$ you can divide by.  So it simplifies things: instead of asking "is $x/y$ defined" for arbitrary $x$ and $y$, we can just ask "is $y^{-1}$ defined" for a single $y$ and then $x/y$ is (or is not) defined for all $x$.  $x/y$ can't be defined for all $x$, $y$, for reasons better explained elsewhere.

Comment: @jcast Perhaps $\frac00$ is defined (and $\frac00=1$) even if $0^{-1}$ is not defined?

Comment: @Mirko: let's try that: $$2=2\times1=2\times\frac00=\frac  {2\times0}0=\frac00=1. $$

Comment: @MartinArgerami But aren't you implicitly assuming that $0^{-1}$ is defined when you write $2\times\frac00=\frac  {2\times0}0$? This looks to me like application of associativity, $2\times\frac00=2\times(0\times0^{-1})=(2\times0)\times0^{-1}=\frac  {2\times0}0$.

Comment: @Mirko: so you want to define $\frac00=1$ but postulate that associativity does not hold?

Comment: @Mirko This is also discussed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1554929/42242), see for example Goblin’s answer to this.

Comment: @k.stm Thank you, I am happy with the link you supplied, it reaches a contradiction without mentioning $0^{-1}$. Copied from there: 

**Proposition 3**: $\frac{0}{0}$ is not a real number

**Proof**: Suppose that $\frac{0}{0} = x$, where $x$ is a real number.

$\frac{0}{0}=x \Leftrightarrow x \cdot 0 = 0 = (x + 1) \cdot 0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{0}{0}=x+1$

$ \therefore x = x + 1 \Leftrightarrow 0 = 1 \Leftrightarrow \bot$

Comment: @MartinArgerami I wanted to define $\frac00$ without reference to $0^{-1}$ (or, alternatively, explain why $\frac00$ does not exist, without reference to $0^{-1}$), as I did not feel that talking about inverses on its own answers the question.

Comment: @Mirko: the whole point of fractions it to talk about inverses.And in the argument you posted you posted you are using inverses, to get $x\cdot0=0$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I do not follow what you are saying. "The whole point" seems too philosophical to me. In my previous comment I copied an argument showing $\frac00$ is not a real number without using the notation $0^{-1}$, so I do not see how I am using inverses.

Comment: @Mirko: First, "the whole point" is not a philosophical matter. Fractions are created so that the expression $1/n$ (that is, the inverse of $n$) makes sense. Writing $\frac1n$ or $n^{-1}$ is only a matter of notation, but there is no difference. And in your argument you use "the inverse of $0$" to go from $x=\frac00$ to $x\cdot 0 = 0$ (otherwise, there is no reason for those two expressions to be equivalent).

Comment: @MartinArgerami By definition $\frac a b =c$ if $a = b\cdot c$. If I wish I  may proceed and define and talk about inverses, but I do not have to.

Comment: @Mirko: you may, if you wish. Now, what would exactly be the point of dealing with fractions but not doing arithmetic with them?

Comment: @MartinArgerami I do not know the answer to your question, but that is not what the OP asked. Say you look at all even integers $E$ with multiplication. There is enough structure to say that (a) $\frac82=4$ since $8=4\cdot2$, (b) $\frac62$ is undefined, as there is no $b\in E$ with $6=b\cdot2$, (c) no unit, not even possible to talk about $2^{-1}$. Is $\frac62$ undefined because $2^{-1}$ isn't (and if so,then how is $\frac82$ defined)? In $\mathbb Z$ there is $1$ and $\frac62=3$, yet no $2^{-1}$. Proof that $\frac00$ is undefined (and couldn't be) works nevertheless, without involving inverses

Answer (score 2):

If $0/0 = x$ then $ 0=0x$ which is true for any value of $x$, meaning there is no unique solution:  $x$ is undefined for this kind of ratio.

So then y/y is undefined unless it is specified that y≠0