# Is my $0^0 = 1$ proof correct?

Tags: proof-verification, definition, exponentiation

Is the following proof that $0^0 = 1$ correct?

Let $k = 0^0$ (assuming it has a meaningful value)

Observe that $k = 0^0 = 0^{n0} = (0^0)^n = k^n$, for all integers $n$.

$\implies k^n - k = 0$, for all $n \in \mathbb Z$.

$\implies k^n - k = 0$ and $k - k^{-n} = 0$, for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

$\implies k[k^{n-1} - 1] = 0$ and $\displaystyle\frac1{k^n}[k^{n+1} - 1] = 0$

$\implies [k = 0$ or $k =$ any $(n-1)$th root of unity$]$ and $[k =$ any $(n+1)$th root of unity$]$

All requirements are satisfied $\iff k = 1$ for any fixed $n$.

Therefore, $k = 0^0 = 1\quad\blacksquare$

Comment: These steps show that if $0^0$ exists, it is 1.  But many of these steps assumes the answer exists in the first place.

Comment: This does not qualify as a proof. You bring in the usual laws of exponents when it is convenient without justification even though there's no reason for them to apply, and you implicitly assume that $k$ is not $0$ when you take negative exponents, but give no reason why it can't be zero.

Comment: "Let $k=0^0$ (assuming it has a meaningful value)".  It isn't.  Whatever your proof continues to say no matter how logical or correct will not and can not be valid.

Comment: Why can't $k=0$ by this argument?

Comment: Similar reasoning: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1554929/zero-divided-by-zero-must-be-equal-to-zero

Comment: Thanks to all that have commented. Your input is greatly appreciated. Originally, I thought that firstly, there is no reason for the usual exponential laws to forcibly not apply. But that includes negative exponentials as well. So my idea was that for the negative exponents to apply, this immediately eliminates k equalling zero. Of course, I never proposed that this proof is legitimate but was merely looking for reasons why it isn't.

Comment: There is the ad hoc convergence theory which states that functions for values without direct meaning may be *extended* to allow general rules to work. We were lucky for $0^0$. In other cases, there is a cost and sometimes a bonus like for $i$ and the original $-2^{\frac12}$

Comment: @Paul: Not even that. It shows that if $0^0$ exists **and is invertible**, it must be $1$; it uses $k^{-n}$ where $k$ is $0^0$.

Comment: See Also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-the-zero-power-is-00-1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is my $0^0 = 1$ proof correct?

**It's not a *proof*, really.** You can never *prove* that something that does not have a meaning has a meaning. You can only *define* it to be so.

However, what you have written is an *informal argument* for the definition $0^0 = 1$, and it's a pretty good argument. Specifically, it's an argument that we should define $0^0 = 1$ IF we want some other properties to hold. What properties? Well, you only really employed one property, namely the law of exponents which says that if $a, b, c$ are integers and $a$ is not zero, then
$$
(a^b)^c = a^{bc}.
$$
Your "proof" is essentially an argument founded on the premise we should allow this to be true when $a = 0$ as well. Assuming that it's true when $a = b = 0$, you derive that $(0^0)^n = 0^0$ and $(0^0)^{-n} = 0^0$, and then go on to conclude that $0^0 = 1$.
So what you've shown is that if we want the above law to be true when $a= b=0$, then we better define $0^0 = 1$.

To be sure, there are many **objections** to your argument:

- You haven't really addressed the possibility that $k = 0^0 = 0$.
  When you take $(0^0)^{-n}$, you are implicitly not allowing $k$ to be $0$.
- Similarly, you haven't really addressed the possibility that $k = \infty$.
- The obvious objection: you've assumed the power law $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$ should hold when $a = b = 0$.
- Finally, you haven't really convinced readers who think that $0^0$ should be left undefined, because you've started out by assuming it has a value.

Fortunately, the first two bullets can be addressed by arguments similar to yours; for instance, if $0^0 = 0^{-0}$, then it should be its own reciprocal, so it doesn't make sense for it to be $0$ or $\infty$.

For the third bullet point, you could address it by considering other properties of exponents and extending them to $0$, and showing that in all or almost all cases $0^0 = 1$ seems to be the most natural. Of course, this won't convince someone who doesn't see any point in extending any of the properties to begin with.

The last bullet is more tricky. In analysis, $0^0$ is an [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form) meaning that we don't want to say that it is $1$ or any other particular number. And, it would actually be generally *bad* in analysis if we were to say that $0^0$ had a value; it would be wrong to assign it any value at all.

---

In summary, I have described what your argument is -- an argument, and not a proof, that $0^0 = 1$, and I think it's a decent argument. And I have discussed some possible objections to it.

In fact, note that $0^0 = 1$ *is* commonly taken to be the definition, used especially in abstract algebra and combinatorics.
[Even Google says it's $1$.](https://www.google.com/#q=0+to+the+power+0)

Comment: You go google!  Do them bad analysis things!

Comment: Why would it be *bad* in analysis to say that $0^0=1$? After all, $x^y$ is discontinuous at $(0,0)$ no matter whether or how we define $0^0$.

Comment: @celtschk Hold on, no. A function can't be discontinuous at a point where it doesn't exist. The "right" thing is to say $x^y$ is not defined at $(0,0)$. Anyway it's not bad as a *notational convention* (e.g. in writing out a Taylor series) but I don't think it's a good definition to take.

Comment: And I claim the "right" thing to do it define $0^0=1$. And you still did not manage to demonstrate any **harm** done by that definition.

Comment: @celtschk **Here is the harm:** $x^y$, for $x, y \ge 0$, becomes discontinuous at $(0,0)$. If that's not enough for you, then fine, no need to be a jerk about it on my answer. You will find that lots of other people agree with me that that is a good reason not to define it, including e.g. [Arturo Magidin in the other thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-the-zero-power-is-00-1/11155#11155).

Comment: The power function is already necessarily discontinuous on a complete ray from $0$ (the branch cut), and definitely is not continuous at $0$ either way, so what would be the harm to define it at one more point connected to the already existing line of discontinuity?

Comment: @celtschk I'm just talking about the real power function, $x^y$ for $x \ge 0$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$. I agree with you that the complex power function, $e^{y \text{Log } x}$ has branch cut troubles either way.

Comment: Ah, I see, you leave $(-1)^2$ undefined as well …

Comment: @celtschk Yes, $(-1)^a$ is not usually defined in the context of a real number power function.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an aside - a more 'proofy' way (if that even makes sense!) to show this is to calculate the (right) limit as $x \rightarrow 0$ of the function $x^x$ and to take this as the definition of $0^0$.

To do this simply note that
$$x^x = e^{x\log x}. $$

Then standard limit rules give
$$0^0 = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} e^{x\log x}= e^0 = 1.$$

Comment: I don't think this is a good argument to conclude $0^0 = 1$. As you can see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/11155/68107), $\lim_{x,y \to 0} x^y$ does't exist, so it doesn't make sense to just pick $x = y$ and then take the limit.

Comment: This is a completely different question and yes it does make sense to consider the case $x=y$ because this is the case when $x$ and $y$ vary in the same way when considering your limit.