# Convergence and value of improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, improper-integrals

I have to prove that integral

$I = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin(t^2)dt$ is convergent. Could you tell me if it's ok?

Let $t^2=u$ then $dt=\frac{du}{2\sqrt{u}}$

Now $$I = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(u)du}{2\sqrt{u}}$$

Which is equal to $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin(u)du}{2\sqrt{u}} + \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(u)du}{2\sqrt{u}}$$

First of these is convergent because of the limit

$$\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{sin(u)}{2\sqrt{u}} = 0$$

Second is convergent from Dirichlet test.

Is it correct?
Also how to find the value of this integral ($\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}}$) ?

Comment: The first is correct. For the second, what is the Dirichlet test (I thought that was something for series)? About the value, when the limit of integration is finite it is given by Fresnel integral (see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FresnelIntegrals.html)). I am not sure there is an elementary way to derive the exact value of this integral.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri A lot of convergence tests work for series and integrals with only small changes in formulation. Then it's common to call both versions by the same name [whether the first discoverer of the test discovered both versions or not].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To evaluate the integral, we analyze the closed-contour integral $I$ given by

$$I=\oint_C e^{iz^2}\,dz$$

where $C$ is comprised of (i) the line segment from $0$ to $R$, (ii) the circular arc from $R$ to $R(1+i)/\sqrt{2}$, and the line segment from $R(1+i)/\sqrt{2}$ to $0$.

Since $e^{iz^2}$ is analytic in and on $C$, Cauchy's Integral Theorem guarantees that $I=0$.  Then, we have

$$\int_0^R e^{ix^2}\,dx+\int_0^{\pi/4}e^{iR^2e^{i2\phi}}iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi-\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^R e^{-x^2}\,dx=0 \tag 1$$

Letting $R\to \infty$, the second integral on the left-hand side of $(1)$ approaches zero.  Therefore, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty e^{ix^2}\,dx&=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx\\\\&=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Finally, equating real and imaginary parts of $(2)$, we obtain

$$\int_0^\infty \sin(x^2)\,dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}}$$

and

$$\int_0^\infty \cos(x^2)\,dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Putting $\sqrt{u}=t$ and $\dfrac{du}{2\sqrt{u}}=dt$,

$$I = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(u)du}{2\sqrt{u}}\\=\int_0^{+\infty} \sin(t^2) dt\\=\int_0^{+\infty}\Im(e^{it^2})dt\\=\Im\left(\int_0^{+\infty}e^{it^2}dt\right)$$

Putting $it^2=-z$ and $t=\sqrt{-\frac1iz}=\sqrt{i}\sqrt{z}$, $$dt = \sqrt{i}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{z}}dz$$

Hence,

\begin{align*}
I &=\Im\left(\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-z}\sqrt{i}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{z}}dz\right)\\
&=\Im\left(\frac{\sqrt{i}}{2}\int_0^{+\infty} z^{-\frac12}e^{-z} dz\right)\\
&=\Im\left(\frac{\sqrt{i}}{2} \Gamma\left(\frac12\right)\right)\\
&=\Im\left(\sqrt{i}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\right)\\
&=\Im\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}(1+i)\sqrt{\pi}\right) \tag{!!}\\
&=\fbox{$\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}}$}
\end{align*}

Now I'm concerned about step $(!!)$ because I don't see why I should take that root of $i$ and not the other one. However since it yields the right answer, I think there must be some reason. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: This development lacks rigor.  Upon enforcing the substitution, the limits of integration were not transformed appropriately.  In addition, it is not true in general that $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ for complex $a$ and $b$.  Caution needs to be taken there. I've posted a solution that shows one way forward.  ;-))

Comment: @Dr.MV Moreover for some weird reason I have to take one particular square root of $i$ and not the other. This really is a ridiculous attempt.

Comment: @Dr.MV Why do you say the limits weren't transformed properly? Isn't $\sqrt{-\infty}=\infty$ ?

Comment: No, $\sqrt{-\infty}=\pm i \infty$.  And in this transformation, one has $\sqrt{i\infty}=\pm\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\infty$.  Then, one must decide on a suitable branch cut to define the square root as a single-valued function.

Comment: @Dr.MV Aren't $\pm\infty$ one and the same thing in complex numbers?

Comment: No they are not.

Comment: @Dr.MV http://math.stackexchange.com/a/127550/229480

Comment: We are talking about two different things.  In the case at hand, you have made a change of variables that augments the integration contour.  It no longer is along the real axis upon enforcing the transformation.  Rather, the new contour lies on a line that is parametrically described by $z=t\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$, where $t\in [0,\infty)$.  The other concept - "the point at infinity - does not interfere here.  The issue is the path.  Now, as it turns out, because the integrand is analytic, the integral is path independent.

Comment: @Dr.MV Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark